# Prove or disprove: If $x^T A x = 0 $ for all $x$, then $ A = 0 $.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix and $x$ be a vector. Now consider the statement:

If $x^T A x = 0 $ for any $x$, then $A = 0$.

Is the above statement true or false?
How would you prove it?

Comment: :what are you trying?

Comment: For such $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n},$ diagonal entries are all $0:$ That $a_{jj}=0~(j=1,2,...,n)$  is evident by considering $x=(x_i)_{n\times 1}$ where $x_i=\begin{cases} 1,&\text{if $i=j$}\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}\\ \end{cases}.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x ^t Ax = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^n $  then the diagonal entries of $A$ 
are all zero by taking $x$ to be the column vector with the $i$-th 
component as  $1$ and $ 0$ elsewhere, $\forall i = 1,2,\ldots, n$.

then choose your $x$ as follows

the column vector with the $i$-th and the $j$-th 
components as  $1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then  try to ahow $A^t=-A$

Comment: can I have the following counterexample? Say, if I choose x = (0,0)^T, then for any 2 x 2 matrix  A with entries not equal to 0 , x^T A x = 0 . Hence the statement is false. Is my logic wrong ???

Comment: Yes it's wrong. We need to find $A$ or some properties of $A$ so that $x^TAx=0$ for absolutely any $x$.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true, $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ is a counterexample.

Take $x=e_i+e_j$, you can get $A_{ij}+A_{ji}=0$, which means $A^T+A=0$

Comment: can I have the following counterexample? Say, if I choose x = (0,0)^T, then for any 2 x 2 matrix  A with entries not equal to 0 , x^T A x = 0 . Hence the statement is false. Is my logic wrong ???

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. You don't choose $x$, the statement in your problem is for *any* x.

Comment: It is wrong. Your counterexample has to satisfy that for all $x$, $x^TAx=0$, not only for $x=0$.

Comment: but in u guys method, u guys also choose x to be blablabla. Plus, if it doesnt hold one for particular vector $x$, then how can i hold for all $x$ ? Sorry, I know i m asking dumb questions but i just want to understand more

Comment: Since it holds for all $x$, it holds in particular for the $x$ that Shu has presented. This allows you to deduce the general form of $A$ satisfying the equation.

Answer (score 3):

furthermore to the disproves of the fellers up, I would like to mention that if the question was in the complex field, the statement was true.

in other words:

$x^*Ax=0 \, \forall x \in C^n  \Leftrightarrow A=0 $

proof:

$\Leftarrow$ this direction is immediate

$\Rightarrow$

since the left side is zero for all x, lets choose few x's to show how A must be zero as well

- $x_1=e_k \Rightarrow x^*Ax=e^T_kAe_k=A_{kk} \Rightarrow A_{kk}=0 \, \forall k$
- $x_2=e_k+e_m \Rightarrow x^*Ax= (e^T_k+e^T_m)A(e_k+e_m)=A_{kk}+A_{km}+A_{mk}+A_{mm} $

since $A_{kk}=A_{mm}=0$ we get $\Rightarrow A_{km}=-A_{mk} \, \forall k\ne m$

- $x_3=e_k+ie_m \Rightarrow x^*Ax= (e^T_k-ie^T_m)A(e_k+ie_m)=A_{kk}+iA_{km}-iA_{mk}+A_{mm} $

$\Rightarrow A_{km}=A_{mk} \, \forall k\ne m$

from $x_2,x_3$ we get that $A_{km}=-A_{km}$ where this can only valid if $A_{km}=0 \, \forall k\ne m$

therefore $A=0 \,\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^tAx=\langle x,Ax\rangle$ (the inner product), the question may be stated:

**Is there a transformation that maps every vector to something orthogonal to itself?**

What should come to mind is a rotation matrix that rotates $\mathbb{R}^2$ by 90 degrees, which Shu Xiao Li has presented.